# Send attachment from Jenkins to Teams

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, microsoft-teams

I recently integrated my Jenkins with Microsoft Teams for notifications.  Through webhook, I am able to push the notifications to the channels under my Team.

Refered - 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Office+365+Connector+Plugin

Now the scenario is I need to send an attachment like build log, etc to be sent out from Jenkins to Teams as like Email editable plugin do.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 4):

Connectors only support [MessageCard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference). There is no option to send attachments using Connectors.

Comment: Thanks Wajeed for this.